# Use winrar decompression how to check password

Tags: c#, winrar

Using winrar decompression, how to detect the password is correct?

```
the_Reg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\WinRAR.exe");
the_Obj = the_Reg.GetValue("");
the_rar = the_Obj.ToString();
the_Reg.Close();
the_Info = "x " + rarName + " " + _unRarPath + " -y -p123456";

ProcessStartInfo the_StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
the_StartInfo.FileName = the_rar;
the_StartInfo.Arguments = the_Info;
the_StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
the_StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = _rarPath;//获取压缩包路径

Process the_Process = new Process();
the_Process.StartInfo = the_StartInfo;
the_Process.Start();
the_Process.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this solution will help you. Here is original post [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/395017/Validate-the-password-for-zip-file-using-DOTNETZIP.)

```
public class ZipPasswordTester
 {
    public bool CheckPassword(Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry entry, string password)
    {
      try
       {
           using (var s = new PasswordCheckStream())
           {
            entry.ExtractWithPassword(s, password);
          }
        return true;
      }
    catch (Ionic.Zip.BadPasswordException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    catch (PasswordCheckStream.GoodPasswordException)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

  private class PasswordCheckStream : System.IO.MemoryStream
  {
       public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
      {
        throw new GoodPasswordException();
       }

    public class GoodPasswordException : System.Exception { }
     }
  }
```